# Reordering a list based on another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists `Ii0` and `Iv0` containing numpy arrays. I am using `argsort()` to reorder elements in `Ii0` to generate a new list `Ii01`. I want to use the same order to reorder elements in `Iv0` to generate a new list `Iv01`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np
Ii0 = [np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 4],[4,3]]),
       np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[4,3],[3,4]])]

Iv0 = [np.array([[10],[20],[30],[40],[50]]),
        np.array([[25],[38],[41],[97],[65],[54]])]

Ii01 = [i[i[:,1].argsort()] for i in Ii0]

Iv01 = [i[i[:,0].argsort()] for i in Iv0]
print("Iv01 =",Iv01)
```

The current output is

```
Iv01 = [array([[10],
       [20],
       [30],
       [40],
       [50]]), array([[25],
       [38],
       [41],
       [54],
       [65],
       [97]])]
```

The expected output is

```
Iv01 = [array([[10],
               [20],
               [30],
               [50],
               [40]]),array([[25],
               [38],
               [41],
               [65],
               [54],
               [97]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Iv01 = [y[x[:,1].argsort()] for x, y in zip(Ii0, Iv0)]
print("Iv01 =",Iv01)
```

**Output**

```
Iv01 = [array([[10],
       [20],
       [30],
       [50],
       [40]]), array([[25],
       [38],
       [41],
       [65],
       [54],
       [97]])]
```

Or as an alternative, use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis):

```
Iv01 = [np.take_along_axis(y, x[:, 1].argsort().reshape((-1, 1)), 0) for x, y in zip(Ii0, Iv0)]
```